# How to best deal with lack of private variable scope inside MySQL functions?

Tags: mysql, scope

I just learned the hard way that when I call a stored function from within a stored function and both have a @result variable, the outside function will pick up the variable from the inside function. How do I avoid this problem apart from trying to create unique variable names? There don't seem to be variables that are private to the function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I **can** create variables with private private scope with:

```
DECLARE varname var_type DEFAULT default_value
```